# Variable xml tag in golang

Tags: xml, go

I'm trying to communicate with a SOAP service from my go program but I'm having difficulties to use the [xml package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/).

Most of the requests I have to send have the following format:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns="namespace1">
 <s:Body>
      <FunctionName xmlns=“namespace2”/>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I feel I have to create one type for each request I want to make, as `FunctionName`changes... [Here](http://play.golang.org/p/Cuuv5ZDtQA)'s the code I use so far.

It would be nice if I could have a single type with the `FunctionName` as an attribute but I just can't figure out how... To make it clearer, I would like to put a variable instead of `FunctionName` inside `xml:"s:Body>FunctionName"`.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`xml.Name`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Name) field to specify the tag name you want it in the XML output. Note that with `xml.Name` you can also specify the namespace, so you don't even need `Command.Field` anymore which you only used to set the namespace attribute.

So here is your modified code:

```
type Command struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
}

type XMLEnvelop struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name `xml:"s:Envelope"`
    Xmlns        string   `xml:"xmlns:s,attr"`
    FunctionName Command  `xml:"s:Body>FunctionName"`
}

v := &XMLEnvelop{Xmlns: "namespace1",
    FunctionName: Command{xml.Name{"namespace2", "MyFuncName"}}}

output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(v, "", "    ")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
}

// Write the output to check
os.Stdout.Write(output)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/zrOQglEYn5)):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="namespace1">
    <s:Body>
        <MyFuncName xmlns="namespace2"></MyFuncName>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```